# How do I put a user and password for sql/xampp when it is default?

Tags: php, sql, xampp

When trying to do sql at home the server wouldn't let me go to the security page for a password and user. I know that the user is root but it won't let me use it when I am uploading it for a website. I dont know what to do...

//connect to the database using: server, user, password, db
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","songs");

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli_connect()` function has 4 parameters,

```
mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

I think you have just forgotton the password parameter, which has to be entered even if it is not set to anything.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '', "songs");
```